# How to combine two distinct mySQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to distinct make AND model like `make, model`

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT distinct make, model FROM used order by make asc");
```

and afterwards

```
    <? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <option value=<?=$row['make']?>><?=$row['make']?></option>
    <? } ?>
```

and

```
 <? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($make)) { ?>
    <option value=<?=$row['model']?>><?=$row['model']?></option>
    <? } ?>
```

but I get only the model to be displayed, and not correct.

Now I am using

```
$make=mysql_query("SELECT distinct make FROM used order by make asc");
$model=mysql_query("SELECT distinct model FROM used order by model asc");
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You could probably join a select so you can do it in one query. `JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT model AS model FROM used ORDER BY model) as t`

Comment: Those two queries are equivalents.

Comment: Also, as an aside `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, you should look into prepared statements in either [PDO](http://uk1.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are misunderstanding what is happening here:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

if you: var_dump($row) then you will see it has both columns in it. i.e $row['make'] and $row['model'] with the values that you expect.

You need to process both columns at once.

I have no idea what this:

```
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($make)) { ?>
    <option value=<?=$row['model']?>><?=$row['model']?></option>
    <? } ?>
```

is doing but it cannot be helpful. It it safe to delete it.

I will not create tested code as the 'mysql_*' functions are depreciated in PHP.